# Placement of adverb of place

Tags: questions

What is the difference of below two sentences?

> 1. I saw Mr. Ram **in the Vegetable Market** repairing a Car.
> 2. **In the Vegetable Market**, I saw Mr. Ram repairing a Car.

Answer (score 1):

Adverbs of place generally appear after the main verb (if the verb is intransitive), or after the object (if the verb is transitive).

In your sentence, the verb *"to see"* is transitive, so normally you should place the adverb after the object.

> I saw Mr. Ram in the Vegetable Market ...

However, it's not wrong to place the adverbial prepositional phrase at the beginning of the sentence. In this case, you are actually adding an **emphasis to the mentioned place**. (This construction is usually found in literary writing.)